# I want to retrieve related fields as JSON format using Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, relationship

> I want to retrieve Student user fields, but I am having a hard time
> trying to figure out how to do that I tried reading docs but still
> confused

**Studentserializer**

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'name', 'course']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        Student_det = Student.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return Student_det
```

**serializer view**

```
def Student_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        stud = Student.objects.all()
        serialized = StudentSerializer(stud, many=True)
        print(serialized.data)
        return JsonResponse(serialized.data, safe=False)
```

**Student Model**

```
class Student (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: Confused with what? What is not being retrieved? Did you mean you want to also display the `user` field as in the User model?

Comment: i wanted to display users info has, i believe what we call nested relationship

Comment: In that case you need to create another serializer for the `User` model, and use that in the `StudentSerializer`

Comment: Hello @AtifShafi check this post it it similar to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67523331/how-to-access-forgin-key-value-in-react-from-django-api

Comment: @bdbd can you post a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66619726/3052106). I think the part about nested serializers is what you need.

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("id", "first_name", "last_name", ) # and you can add other fields here "email", "date_joined", etc.


class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ("id", "user", "name", "course", )
```

This will serialize your Student model like

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Example",
    "last_name": "User"
  }
  "name": "student name",
  "course": "course name"
}
```